# LoadDerivativeCoefficients is zero

Tags: finite-element-method

Why the LoadDerivativeCoefficients are zero in the following example?

```
<< "NDSolve`FEM`"
Ω = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 >= 1, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[Ω];

c = IdentityMatrix[2];

eqns = {Inactive[Div][(-c.Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}] + {1, 0}), {x, y}] == 
    0, DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x^2 + y^2 == 1], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1, 
    x == 2 || x == -2 || y == 2 || y == -2]};

NDSolve`ProcessEquations[eqns, u, {x, y} ∈ mesh][[1]][
   "FiniteElementData"][
  "PDECoefficientData"]["LoadDerivativeCoefficients"]
```

Output is

```
{{{{0}, {0}}}}
```

Instead of

```
{{{{1}, {0}}}}
```

Comment: Someone downvoted this question, which is a bit of a mystery to me. Perhaps the person that downvoted can give a reason. Not understanding a question does not necessarily mean that it is a bad question. I this is a succinct question that is quite to the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options to go about this. Either you split the addition into two `Inactive[Div]` like so:

```
op = 
  Inactive[Div][-c.Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + 
   Inactive[Div][{1, 0}, {x, y}];
```

Or, as an alternative, you Inactivate the `Plus` like so:

```
op = 
  Inactive[Div][
   Inactive[Plus][-c.Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}], {1, 0}], {x, y}];

eqns = {op == 0, 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x^2 + y^2 == 1], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1, 
    x == 2 || x == -2 || y == 2 || y == -2]};

NDSolve`ProcessEquations[eqns, u, {x, y} \[Element] mesh][[1]][
   "FiniteElementData"][
  "PDECoefficientData"]["LoadDerivativeCoefficients"]

{{{{1}, {0}}}}
```